# Webview - Custom URL scheme to open Android Brower

Tags: android, url, browser, webview, url-scheme

I know that you can use URL schemes to open some apps, if they are properly configured.

I want to know if there is a scheme that can open the browser app, so that I can use a link in my app Webview to instruct the Android device to open the URL in the native browser instead of in the webview.

--
I know that the behavior can be set programmatically, however the requirement is to don't modify the existing code to do this behavior.

Comment: Any `http` or `https` link, by default, will open in the native browser. If you implemented `WebViewClient` and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, you need to put smarts in there to indicate what links should stay in the `WebView` and what links should pop open a browser.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm asking about schemes; I know that you can determine what you can do with any URL. However I have a productive app which I would like to redirect users to native browser.

Comment: `http` and `https` *are* schemes. *And* by default they will open a browser, unless you are preventing it from doing so. Moreover, there are lots of browsers, and none of them have to offer support for any schemes other than `http` and `https`.

Comment: @CommonsWare if i open a link in a webview like http:// ... it will open that URL inside the webview, it won't open the native browser.

Comment: "if i open a link in a webview like http:// ... it will open that URL inside the webview" -- not by default. *You* are causing that, via `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` routing the event back to the `WebView`. Default behavior for links and server-side redirects is to open the resulting URL in the default Web browser (or invoke a chooser, if the user has multiple matching activities and no default).

Comment: BTW, you can see this behavior in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WebKit/Browser1). Fire it up, click on a link, and the link goes to the browser.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are right I created a new app and that's the behavior; somewhat unexpected. I guess i won't be able to open the browser then.